# How to change template yii2 (ElaAdmin)

Tags: templates, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I need help to change template default in yii2 to ElaAdmin. anyone help me please. I have the template and yii2-basic template

Comment: have you search on google or inside SO?have you try something?

Answer (score 0):

Just drop your template CSS files in web/css folder and js files in web/js folder(create folder if necessary).

And add paths in appAsset files in /assets/AppAsset.php
For example, adding bootstrap.min.css which is in /css/bs3/css/bootstrap.min.css

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        'css/bs3/css/bootstrap.min.css', // line added

        ['css/print.css', 'media' => 'print'],
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Alternatively, you can add these files directly to main.php in views/layout/main.php 
like

```
<link href="<?=Yii::getAlias('@web');?>/bs3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You can get additional info here.
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets